# How to iterate a value based on an object value in django template

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a model which is 'Saloon' class. I want to iterate saloon name based on the value of capacity. I tried many answers (*forloop.counter, Custom template tags and filters*) but could not manage to do it.

I only want to repeat the saloon's building and name based on the capacity value

**models.py**

```
class Saloon(models.Model):
    building= models.CharField(max_length=55)
    name= models.CharField(max_length=125)
    capacity= models.IntegerField()
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Saloon

def salonogrenci(request):
    saloons = Saloon.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'salonogrenci/home.html', {'saloons':saloons })
```

**home.html**

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <tbody>
     {% for saloon in saloons %}
        {% for i in range(saloon.kapasite) %}
           <tr>
              <th scope="row">{{ saloon.building }}</th>
              <td>{{ saloon.name }}</td>
           </tr>
        {% endfor %}
     {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Example:

```
Saloon building: 'AA'
Saloon name:'ABC'
Saloon capacity:3

Saloon building: 'BB'
Saloon name:'EDF'
Saloon capacity:2
```

Table will be like this as in the html file

```
AA ABC
AA ABC
AA ABC
BB EDF
BB EDF
```

Comment: Thanks. I put more explanation about the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might make more sense to implement this logic at the *view-side*. For example by using a list comprehension function that will generate a list that contains the `Saloon` object multiple times:

```
def salonogrenci(request):
    saloons = [s for s in Saloon.objects.all() for __ in range(s.capacity)]
    return render(request, 'salonogrenci/home.html', {'saloons':saloons })
```

Then you can simply iterate over the `saloons` variable and render the rows individually, like:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <tbody>
     {% for saloon in saloons %}
       <tr>
          <th scope="row">{{ saloon.building }}</th>
          <td>{{ saloon.name }}</td>
       </tr>
     {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I received this error 'TypeError: 'DeferredAttribute' object cannot be interpreted as an integer'. Possibly because of "for __ in range(saloon.capacity)"

Comment: @LandOwner: it should have been `s.capacity`. Sorry.